# Need to find CSS Selector for Material Design 2's md-dialog-container

Tags: css, angular, material-design

Desperately trying to find a selector for md-dialog-container in angular 2's material design with no success.

I can make changes in f12 of chrome with no problem, but carrying out those changes with a valid selector in css is a problem. Researched /deep/ but it is now deprecated.

I have tried `md-dialog-container {}`, `md-dialog-container.md-dialog-container{}`, and `md-dialog-container.md-dialog-container[role="dialog"]` with no success.

Attached are images of me making these changes in f12 of chrome with no problem.

[image: Normal padding of md-dialog-container]

[image: Removed padding of md-dialog-container in Chrome Tools]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're running into is due to ViewEncapsulation. By default, Angular2 uses an emulated Shadow DOM which prevents styles from components affecting each other. You can opt out of ViewEncapsulation (not recommended) or you could [use the /deep/ selector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#-deep-). According to Angular documentation in the link provided it is alright to use this selector using Angular's default emulated Shadow DOM.

From my understanding, Angular has its own CSS processor that should should make it alright for you to use these selectors for right now. I assume they're translated. If using these is truly not an option for you, you'll have to switch to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core'; // and any other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: './my-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-selector.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. This indeed works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE Edge .               ' /deep/ md-dialog-container {} '

Answer (score 13):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Set this on the dialog component itself:

> encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

2. In the parent component set the panelClass on open e.g.

> ```
> this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myDialogComponent, {
>   panelClass: 'my-dialog'
>  });
> ```

3. In the css for the dialog component specifiy the panelClass e.g.

> ```
> .my-dialog {
>
>     .mat-dialog-container {
>         padding: 0;
>      }
> }
> ```

Comment: works well, thanks. The ViewEncapsulation.None step is not required if you're setting styles in your global CSS file

Comment: Makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

For Angular and Material >6.x, I was able to use the ::ng-deep selector:

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every option mentioned above, but somehow with Angular 2 none seemed to work. I finally got it working by adding this line to my css.

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me was:

In the parent component set the `panelClass` on open e.g.

```
 this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myDialogComponent, {
   panelClass: 'my-dialog'
  });
```

3. In the css

```css
  .my-dialog .mat-dialog-container{
     padding:0 !important;
 }
```

The benefit of above solution is that it will only remove padding from a specific dialog not all dialogs in the application.

Comment: this works, but there's no need to duplicate answer above